# Is performance gained when using continue in a for-loop with many if-statements?

Tags: java, performance, for-loop

I have a for loop in a java program which iterates through a set of maps.

Inside the loop I have around 10 different if-statements which checks the name of each key inside the each map.

Example:

```
for (<String, Object> map : object.entrySet()) {
  if (map.getKey().equals.("something") {
    do_something;
    continue;   
  }
  if (map.getKey().equals.("something_else") {
    do_something_else;
    continue;
  }
  if ...
}
```

Do I gain any performance when adding continue-statements like this?

When I step through my code in my IDE and NOT have these continue statements, each if-statement will be tested even if the first one matches.

If I have them like this and the first if matches, the for loop will skip the next 9 if-statements and continue with the next object. 
Maybe the compiled code will treat it differently and the added continue-statements actually makes the loop slower?

Comment: `Inside the loop I have around 10 different if-statements which checks the name of each key inside the each map.` I would stop right there and make sure that doesn't happen. Never mind performance, that's awful code to read. Write clean code first, think about performance later. (Not to mention that cleaner code is more likely to perform better.)

Comment: @komen I know you've already accepted an answer, but I've added mine which I believe can improve seriously your code. Please take a look. tks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of using `continue` all the time, do the `getKey()` just once and use `else if`:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    if (key.equals("something")) {
        // ...
    } else if (key.equals("something else")) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Or use a `switch` statement:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    switch (entry.getKey()) {
        case "something":
            // ...
            break;

        case "something else":
            // ...
            break;
}
```

Comment: Not to mention that the key should probably be an enum and not a string.

Comment: for switch statement: if the case is "something else" then entry.getKey() will be called twice as well right?

Comment: @HRgiger No, the `entry.getKey()` will be called only once for the `switch` statement, no matter how many cases there are.

Answer (score 4):

If you want the current iteration to end after the first condition evaluates to true, you should use `if-else-if-...-else`. In my opinion, that's more clear than using `continue`, since that's what this syntax exists for.

```
for (<String, Object> map : object.entrySet()) {
  if (map.getKey().equals.("something") {
    do_something;  
  }
  else if (map.getKey().equals.("something_else") {
    do_something_else;
  }
  else if (...) {
      ...
  }
  ... else {
      ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Changed to else if and the execution behaved exactly like continue but made the code look more clear.

Answer (score 1):

With your current implementation, yes you are gaining a performance boost by skipping the remaining if statements using the `continue` keyword, although with only a constant of ten "if" statements, it's not that bad (10n = O(n) time). Having said that, the more practical way to approach this, as Eran stated, is to make use of `else if` statements, which will achieve the same result that you are currently using.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have just a few values, IMO, you'll have a **real** performance improvement here if you map your strings to ints, since the int comparison is **far** faster than a String comparison.

Check this out

```
public class Lab1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        usingStrings();
        usingInts();


    }

    private static void usingInts() {
        int[] samples = new int[100000000];
        int[] values = {1,2,3,4};
        for(int i=0;i<samples.length-1;i++) {
            samples[i] = values[(int)(Math.random()*values.length)];
        }
        int total = 0;
        long ini = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for(int i=0;i<samples.length-1;i++) {
            if (1 == (samples[i])) {
                total+=doSomeJob();
            }else if (2 == (samples[i])) {
                total+=doSomeJob();
            }else if (3 == (samples[i])) {
                total+=doSomeJob();
            }else {
                total+=doSomeJob();
            }

        }
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Ints="+(end-ini));
    }

    private static void usingStrings() {
        String[] samples = new String[100000000];
        String[] values = {"one mule","two mules","three mules","four mules"};
        for(int i=0;i<samples.length-1;i++) {
            samples[i] = values[(int)(Math.random()*values.length)];
        }
        int total = 0;
        long ini = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for(int i=0;i<samples.length-1;i++) {
            if ("one mule".equals(samples[i])) {
                total+=doSomeJob();
            }else if ("two mules".equals(samples[i])) {
                total+=doSomeJob();
            }else if ("three mules".equals(samples[i])) {
                total+=doSomeJob();
            }else {
                total+=doSomeJob();
            }
        }
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Strings="+(end-ini));
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static int doSomeJob() {
        int c = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<1000;i++) {
            c++;
        }
        return c;
    }
}
```

output

```
Strings=962
Ints=6
```

which is actually how DBMS indexes work behind the scenes

Comment: No, it is not 'how DBMS indexes work behind the scenes'. Most table keys are far too long to be mapped to integers in the first place, and DBMS implementations don't use chains of `if-elses`, which in any case should be replaced by a `switch`.